# Curious about gaps between lines

Tags: css, typography

Below there is a two example. Only difference is font family between examples but the second one have gaps between lines. Why there is visible gaps between lines in second example?

HTML:

```
<span>This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.</span>
```

[Example 1 in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgj2a1ka/67/)

CSS:

```
span{
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Result: [image: Example 1]

[Example 2 in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgj2a1ka/68/)

CSS:

```
span{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Result: [image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Arial font has a line-height of 1.16. You can change it with `line-height: 1.0;` or higher value property.

Comment: But what is the reason? Is every font has self line-height? Or as a result of computation of browser? I think there is more complex things.

Comment: Lucida Sans Unicode seems to be the same as `line-height: 1.23` so I would say every font has self line-height. Also here https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/line-height it says that `Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.`

Comment: After months I found this, you are right, every font have own height, article is long but it describe very well: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align